# How to update position of a product with shopify api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

i 've read the shopify documentation it specifies to add an collect to the custom collection with the product id. but how to achieve this with shopify_api in rails

i've tried this it responds with an 404.

```
customCollection = ShopifyAPI::CustomCollection.find("875454444547")
customCollection.collects = [
  {
    "product_id": 21548151215,
    "position": 7
  },
  {
    "id": 875454444547,
    "position": 2
  }
]
 customCollection.save
```

Comment: If it returns 404, it probably means that the collection does not exist? Can you check and confirm that the custom collection exists in your shop?

Comment: yes it exists. i need to know is this the right way  because i couldn't find any documentation.@TheLazyLog

Comment: I think it's because there's no direct methods for u to do so with the [api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/b351a815a802e872154734deb7812f355f63b013/lib/shopify_api/resources/custom_collection.rb).

Comment: Can u edit the Collect using `ShopifyAPI::Collect`